# How to ensure protocol conformance at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, runtime, protocols, duck-typing

```
@interface Dog : NSObject
@end

@implementation Dog
- (id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"quacks"])
        return YES;
}
@end
```

The above allows to leverage KVC and write something like :

`[[Dog new] valueForKey:@"quacks"]; // YES`

However, can the objc runtime be used to leverage the same KVC mechanism, AND conform to the Duck protocol at runtime ?

```
@protocol Duck <NSObject>
@optional
  @property (readonly) BOOL quacks;
@end

id<Duck> dug = (id<Duck>)[Dog new];
dug.quacks; // YES
```

Comment: `return YES` YES is not an object

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your question, but there is the method on NSObject:

```
- (BOOL)conformsToProtocol:(Protocol *)aProtocol
```

You can use this to test if an object conforms to a particular protocol. For more fine grained control you can use:

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)selector
```

to test if an object will respond to a message before sending one.

Comment: conformsToProtocol doesn't work unless the class is declared to implement that protocol

Answer (score 0):

"conform to the Duck protocol at runtime"

You cannot "conform to a protocol at runtime". You can use the `respondsToSelector:` check to check for a selector at runtime. However, I believe that that will still not work for messages handled via `valueForUndefinedKey:`.